# how to change fragment views programmatically from the parent activity

Tags: android

I am having a fragment that contains for example one button, I want to allow the Activity containing the fragment to change this button view like for example color and title or src Image.
What's the best way to do that ?

**Update** : sorry If I wasn't clear enough but I want the activity to change the whole view as it's likes , like setting the padding, the color or anything.
It will create the view programmatically and the fragment should replace the old view by the new one and change the view's ID so that the fragment code isn't affected. And If i created methods in the fragment that takes these views when should the Main activity call them ? since the activity has to wait for the layout of the fragment to be created.

Comment: Using [interfaces](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating).

Comment: can't I pass the views in the bundle ?

Answer (score 0):

**1. You must get you fragment from your activity**

```
val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("tag")
```

*or*

```
val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment)
```

**2. Create a method that will do what you wants in you fragment and call this method from the activity**

```
fragment.hideButton()
```

or you can use interface

Answer (score 0):

Try this way according to your requirement

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
    BaseActivity yourActivity;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

   @Override
   public void onAttach(Context context) {
       super.onAttach(context);
      yourActivity = (BaseActivity) context;
   }

   @Override
   public void onDetach() {
       yourActivity = null;
       super.onDetach();
    }


    public void refreshview(){} 

    public void setDada(Data data){}


    @override
    publicn void onStart(){
        yourActivity.setCurrentOpenedFragment(this);
    }
}
```

**Create the BaseActivity class**

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
     public void setCurrentOpenedFragment(BaseFragment currentFragment){}
}
```

**Extends the BaseFragment in your fragment i.e.**

```
public class YourFragment extends BaseFragment{
   View view;       
   Button button;
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
          view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
          button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
          return view;
    }

    @override
    publicn void onStart(){
      super.onStart();
      //yourActivity.setCurrentOpenedFragment(this);
   }

   Data data; 
   @override 
   public void setDada(Data data){
     this.data = data;
   } 
    @Override 
    public void refreshview() {
       button.setcolor(data.getcolor());
    }
}
```

**Write the below line of code in your Activity class**

```
public class YourActivity extends BaseActivity{

   public static final byte NONE =  -1;
   public static final byte HOME =  1;

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);
            changeFragment(new YourFragment(), HOME);
            initview();
    }

   public void initview(){
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
          if(currentFragmentOnDrawer != null){

            Data data = new Data();
            data.setColor(getResource().getcolor(R.color.red));
            currentFragmentOnDrawer.setDada(data);

            currentFragmentOnDrawer.refreshview()

         }
       });
   }

   BaseFragment currentFragmentOnDrawer;
    @Override
    public void setCurrentOpenedFragment(BaseFragment currentFragment) {
        super.setCurrentOpenedFragment(currentFragment);
        this.currentFragmentOnDrawer = currentFragment;
    }

   public void changeFragment(Fragment targetFragment, byte state) {

      FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
      ft.replace(R.id.main_fragment, targetFragment, "" + state);
      ft.addToBackStack("" + state);
      ft.commit();
  }
}
```

Hope it will help for you

Comment: how will this work if refreshView method is called in the onCreate of the Activity?

Comment: hi, please check the updated answer in activity, you can update your fragment view inside the refreshView method from the activity oncreate method, it is just a way of managing and updating view, you can manage it according to your requirement

Comment: the above code is the best way of managing the fragment in activity, you can try this way of coding for multiple fragment also

Comment: This doesn't explain how to pass a complete view from activity to fragment

Comment: Hi..i have improved and updated my answer in standard way
- changeFragment(new YourFragment(), HOME);  will show the yourFragment in front of activity, you can use this method for for other fragment also to show.
- call the setdata(with fragment view setting pojo) and refreshview method from where you want not just from button click. 
- setCurrentOpenedFragment() in this override method you will get the current fragment object.
- currentFragmentOnDrawer.refreshview() this method will update the view from where you want.

Comment: Ohh I am so sorry for not being able to try your answer due to the army service :3 :3 but from reading the code I think u change the views when a button is clicked, but What I wanted to do is to make the activity change the views of the fragment at the time fragment is being initialized.