# Custom List view with Fragments

Tags: android

I am working on custom list view which access inbox messages it is working fine with simple main activity project. But as i am trying 
with "fragments" activity its not working.Can Anyone help me.

```
public class tab2 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab2, container, false);
        ListView listView = view.findViewById(R.id.messageList);   
        return view;    
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        List<smsdata> smsList = new ArrayList<>();    
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor c;    
        assert getContentResolver() != null;
        c=getContentResolver().query(uri,null,null,null,null);
        assert c != null;
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
                    smsdata sms = new smsdata();
                    sms.setBody(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")));
                    sms.setNumber(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")));
                    smsList.add(sms);

                    c.moveToNext();
                }

            }
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        c.close();    
    }
    private ContentResolver getContentResolver() {
        return null;
    }    
}
```

Below is the list adapter class it is working in both type of activities.But i don't know how to set adapter

```
 public class listadapter extends ArrayAdapter<smsdata> {
    TextView text;
    TextView text2;
    private Context context;
    private List<smsdata>smsList;
    public listadapter(Context context,List<smsdata>smsList){
        super(context,R.layout.fragment_tab2,smsList);
        this.context=context;
        this.smsList=smsList;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        @SuppressLint("ViewHolder") View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab2,parent,false);

        text = rowView.findViewById(R.id.smsNumberText);
        text.setText(smsList.get(position).getNumber());

        text2 = rowView.findViewById(R.id.smsDetail);
        text2.setText(smsList.get(position).getBody());
        return rowView;


    }

}
```

Comment: where are you anitiate the adapter and set it to the listview ?

Comment: yes i don't know how to initiate adapter and set it to list view can u help

Comment: Try the way of manage fragment inside the activity from https://stackoverflow.com/a/58489808/4042384

Comment: sorry i didn't get that

Answer (score 0):

**first you classes need to be remane ! a class always begin with a uppercase**

change tab2 to Tab2Fragment

change listadapter to SmsAdapter

**then to initiate your fragment you just have to create it and assign it to the listView. the listview must be a variable of your fragment or a variable in your oncreate method only**

```
public class tab2 extends Fragment {
    private ListView listView
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab2, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        listView = view.findViewById(R.id.messageList);      
        List<smsdata> smsList = new ArrayList<>();    
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor c;    
        assert getContentResolver() != null;
        c=getContentResolver().query(uri,null,null,null,null);
        assert c != null;
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
                    smsdata sms = new smsdata();

                    sms.setBody(c.getString(
                        c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")));

                    sms.setNumber(c.getString(
                        c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")));
                    smsList.add(sms);

                    c.moveToNext();
                }

            }
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        c.close();    
        listadapter adapter = new listadapter(smsList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    private ContentResolver getContentResolver() {
        return null;
    }    
}
```

**But i really suggest you to use RecyclerView instead of ListView**
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Comment: It is showing an error near (listadapter adapter = new listadapter(smsList);)

Comment: sorry but i wonder if you are able to do something by yourself ? what is the error ? if you're adapter code correct without error ?

Comment: listadapter adapter = new listadapter(smsList);  the error is here

Comment: is there any other way to do so? i mean for adapter

Comment: what is the error ?!!!!! have you renamed your adapter ? have you importe the adapter in the import section of you class ? (import com.<youtcompany>.listadapter:)

Comment: listView.setAdapter(adapter); now the error is showing here