# Could not find Fragment constructor, when app comes back from landscape Camera

Tags: android

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
>   Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app1/com.example.app1.MainActivity}: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.app1.ui.template.TemplateFragment: could not find Fragment constructor

When I take a photo in landscape orientation (everything is well in portrait mode) and save it from Camera, this error occurs. 
Orientation of my app is only portrait.

Constructor of TemplateFragment:

```java
public TemplateFragment(){

} 

public static  TemplateFragment newInstance(int equipmentId) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("equipmentId", equipmentId);
        TemplateFragment f = new TemplateFragment();
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }
```

Error occurs in MainActivity

```java
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //on this line
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: Is your `TemplateFragment` a non-static inner class?

Comment: @laalto no, just
public class TemplateFragment extends Fragment

Comment: and not an inner class of another class?

Comment: @laalto not an inner class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this below way of code

Write in fragment class

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
 public TemplateFragment(){

 }
```

Write in manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".yourActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Write in Activity class

```
@Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

     Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.main_fragment);
      fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 }
```

you can see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58489808/4042384 for fragment in activity

Hope it will help for you